# Get a div to fade out on mouse hover of another div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm trying to get .image img to fade out when description-box is hovered.

```
$(".description-box").on({
mouseover: function () {
    clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".image img").fadeOut();
},
mouseout : function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () { 
        $(".image img").fadeIn();
    }, 100);
}
});
```

*EDIT*

https://jsfiddle.net/pugu9vyy/

Comment: What is the error? Also, show us your HTML code

Comment: can you add a fiddle?

Comment: why don't you just use css? http://jsfiddle.net/5nqLkm3f/1/

Comment: @Rachel Gallen I'd like to have a div over that pic to trigger the fade of the pic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Something like this maybe... [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/e058q7m8/)

```
$(".description-box").on({
mouseover: function () {
    timer = setTimeout(function () {
        $(".image img").fadeOut();
    }, 100);
},
mouseout: function () {
clearTimeout(timer);
    $(".image img").fadeIn();

}
});
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this:

```
$(".description-box").on({
    mouseenter: function () {
        $('.image img').css('opacity', '0');
    },
    mouseleave: function () {
        $('.image img').css('opacity', '1');
    }
});
```

see fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/pugu9vyy/1/

Comment: Thanks!  If I wanted to add a delay I would use this command?  $('.image img').delay(1000).css('opacity', '0');